# Counting rows per special character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, special-characters, patindex

I have identify records that contain non-Alpha characters.  I know how to do that part. I am using first and last name fields.  The odd part of this is that I have to provide a count of rows per character.  So for example, 500 rows contain $, 400 rows contain &, and so on. Dashes are Ok, and periods are ok if they are contained in a suffix. Is there any good way to pull and display this in a table format? Maybe a column that contains the characters and then a second column that has the counts of records that contain that character.  I am on SQL Server.  Thanks!

Here is an example of the output I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Adding sample data, and desired output is always appreciated.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If one row contains & and $ you have to count them for each specific case, right? How do you need to see the result? If you can have one column per symbol you can just do a COUNT and it should work.